# Playstation 3. "Plug in Controller USB and Press PS Button" Wired 3rd party controller

Tags: ps3

I am trying to fix a PS3 for the kids I work with.  When turned on it displays "Plug in Controller USB and press PS button"  The only controller I have is a 3rd party wired controller.  I plug it in and push button.  Nothing happens.  Have tried Hard reseting console, changing outlets and nothing is working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the third party controller is for use with a PS3, what make and model of controller is it? If the controller is old or hasn't been used in a while it might just need charged for a while before it works.

Comment: Its a PS3 controller.  its also wired so there is no charging it.